# $(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})(y+\sqrt{y^2+1})=1$ is true if and only if $x+y=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})(y+\sqrt{y^2+1})=1$ is true if and only if $x+y=0$

I believe x and y could both be 0 as that satisfies the equations. Beyond that, I do not know how to prove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A short way:**

Let $x=\sinh u$ and $y=\sinh v$. This turns the equation to $e^ue^v=1$.

As the hyperbolic sine is odd and invertible, $u=-v\iff x=-y$.

---

**Another short way:**

After simplification,
$$\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x+\sqrt{y^2+1}-y\right)\left(\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}+y\right)-1\right)\\
=2x+2y=0.$$

As the factor $\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x+\sqrt{y^2+1}-y\right)$ is guaranteed to be positive, the proof works both ways.

Comment: Reworded the first part.

Comment: @zwim: bad luck. It seems that this version is more natural, and even calls for the same notation !

Comment: No pb, I delete mine and give credit to this one. Timing is all :-)

Comment: While the first method looks very elegant, I have not learned hyperbolic functions yet. Can you expand on your second method, how did you get the first factor? And how does it being positive impact the proof?

Comment: @T.Rowaway: I could have said nonzero. I found the factor by noticing that $X^{-1}XY=X^{-1}, Y^{-1}XY=Y^{-1}$ then $X+X^{-1}$ and $Y+Y^{-1}$ are simple.

Comment: I see, thank you very much! Your comment clarified everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})(y+\sqrt{y^2+1}) = 1$$
$$x+\sqrt{x^2+1} = \sqrt{y^2+1} - y$$
$$x+y = -\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}$$
$$(x+y)(\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1}) = -x^2+y^2$$
$$(x+y)(\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1} +x-y) = 0$$

Now, you get $x+y=0$ or $\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{y^2+1} +x-y = 0$. Can you go further?

Comment: Your answer in general is a bit hard to follow as you reorder terms quite frequently while moving between sides of the equation. Also I don't understand your last step, when you place -x^2+y^2 back into the parenthesis on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$x+\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sqrt{1+y^2}-y$$

WLOG $x=\cot2A,y=\cot2B$

$$x+\sqrt{1+x^2}=\cot A$$

$$\sqrt{1+y^2}-y=\tan B$$

$$\cot A=\tan B=\cot(90^\circ-B)$$

$A=180^\circ+90^\circ-B\implies2A=?,\cot2A=?$

Answer (score 0):

By continuous rearranging and squaring:
$$\text{Equation} \Rightarrow x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{y+\sqrt{y^2+1}} \Rightarrow x+y=\sqrt{y^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2+1} \Rightarrow$$
$$1-xy=\sqrt{x^2y^2+x^2+y^2+1} \Rightarrow (x+y)^2=0.$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you went from $\sqrt{x^2y^2+x^2+y^2+1}$ to $(x+y)^2$

Comment: By squaring both sides and canceling like terms...